# Slow performance of X509Certificate2.PrivateKey

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I'm loading a certificate from the certificate store. So I have a X509Certificate2 object.
Next I load the private key which I use for signing a message. The code I'm using is:

```
public static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    var enhCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider().CspKeyContainerInfo;
    var privateKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey; //very slow
    var cspparams = new CspParameters(enhCsp.ProviderType, enhCsp.ProviderName, privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName);
    return new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspparams);
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the line:
`var privateKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;`
takes very very long. Around 9 seconds on my laptop. It would seem that this does not happen every time I try to access the private key. Sometimes it's in the order of milliseconds and other times it takes as long as described.

Any insight into why? Is there a way to avoid that?

**UPDATE:**
I've been experimenting a bit after noticing this [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/948080) and some other SO [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303874/rotten-performance-of-rsacryptoserviceprovider-verifydata).
It really seems like that delay is never there when there is no network connectivity.
I wonder if I really have to go decompiling .NET assemblies to sort this out...

**UPDATE 1:**
It appears as though certificates/key pairs that are issued by a real authority are not affected. I'm seeing this issue when trying to load private key for issuers which I've manually added to the trusted root certification authorities

Comment: Is your private key stored on a hardware device? Certificates can be cached on the PC, private keys cannot for obvious reasons... Password based decryption of private keys may also take a long time.

Comment: The private key is stored locally in the cert store. It is not password protected.